# Custom Ubuntu gets stuck on LightDM

Tags: lightdm, live-cd

I recently used Ubuntu Builder to customize the Ubuntu Mini Remix 12.10. I added Openbox, and some other stuff.

I also added a guest user so that the LiveCD wouldn't be running root. After this,, it made sense to install LightDM as well.

However, after building the LiveCD and running in VirtualBox, I chose the "Try Ubuntu without Installing" option, which gave me a LightDM screen. I tried to login in to the guest user (and entered the correct password) but it brought me back to the lightDM screen, and never on to Openbox.

How do I configure LightDM to not do this? Do I even need lightDM in the LiveCD? Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Never Mind. I fixed the problem by adding the line :

user-session=openbox

to the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Comment: In 8 hours, you'll be able to [post your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) providing the solution. I highly recommend doing that, as then it will help others. (Without an answer, it won't be clear to people searching that this is solved.)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by adding this line to the file /etc/ligthdm/lightdm.conf:

```
user-session=openbox
```